# "Request has expired" with "Make your site social" (Gigya) plugin

Tags: plugins, login

I am using WordPress 3.0.5 and am trying to integrate the Gigya API for user registration and login. I get *"Error: Request has expired"* every time I try to register.

With LinkedIn:

[image: Error message with LinkedIn]

With Yahoo!:
[image: Error message with Yahoo!]

Comment: I am making a new blog and I have the same problem. I have configure Google and Twitter accounts on gigya.com.
I have configure Wordpress Pluggin.
I have entered a CNAME (Advanced options in gigya.com 'settings' section) as they say is needed for google accounts and some others (also redirect from subdomain).

Answer (score 1):

here is the fix:
- set the time on your server to nist time:
ntpdate time.nist.gov

the server time needs to be the same with facebook time